# Classifying Topos of a Classical First-order Theory

Tags: logic, topos-theory, categorical-logic

This [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+category) page shows a chart describing the structure of the classifying topos of a theory in various logics, but it doesn't have an entry for the classifying topos of a classical first-order theory.

Do they always exist? If not, is there a standard counterexample and characterization for when it does?

Comment: The notion of classifying topos only applies to geometric logic and to sublogics, such as regular and coherent logic.

Comment: @MarkSaving Is there something about classical first-order logic which makes the definition not apply? I am vaguely familiar with the related constructions. To my understanding, you take sheaves on the syntactic category after turning it into a site and consider geometric morphisms to it from Set. Classical first-order theories do have syntactic categories and it's not obvious to my why you can't turn it into a site and consider the category of sheaves on it, and then geometric morphisms from Set.

Comment: @T-Biconditional My understanding is that you can do that, but the geometric morphisms no longer capture what they would if the starting theory was geometric.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Would happen to have a reference for this?

Comment: Not offhand (this isn't my area of expertise), maybe @MarkSaving can recommend one.

Comment: Thinking about this further, it seems things should actually work out for classical (but not intuitionist) logic. This is because every coherent functor from a Boolean category to a Heyting category will be a Heyting functor. So essentially, we can treat a classical theory as a coherent theory.

Comment: I believe that's the Morleyisation trick.

Comment: I think a reference is: Classifying toposes for first-order theories, Carsten Butz, Peter Johnstone.

Comment: [Here](https://www.brics.dk/RS/97/20/index.html) is a legal-but-paywall-free link to the Butz/Johnstone paper that Ingo recommended. (It's also available through sciencedirect, but that site sometimes has paywalls.)